# An inequality for arctan$x$

Tags: calculus

Why it is true that $|\arctan x-\arctan y|\leq |x-y|$?
I have tried to use $\tan x$ but I didn't conclude to something.

Comment: Use the Mean Value Theorem (i.e. differentiate $\arctan$)

Answer (score 2):

$$\arctan x-\arctan y=\frac{x-y}{1+z^2}$$
where $x<z<y$. This holds by the mean value theorem and proves the result.